# Unity - Detect collision with a specific tile, depending on physics shape

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cell, collider

I have my game set up to detect collisions with a TilemapCollider2D. All of my tiles have their own custom physics shapes (half cells, triangles, etc.), and so far this part works.

Now, I want to have the ability to not only detect a collision, but also detect which tile that collision was with. Most solutions I've been able to find involve finding the cell coordinates of the collision, through `tileMap.WorldToCell(worldPos)`, which would work great with square tiles. However, since my physics shapes are VERY irregular (sometimes much larger than a single cell), I need something that can detect based on the physics shape itself which tile was hit.

If this isn't possible with the TilemapCollider2D then I may have to find a solution using multiple colliders. Any idea of the best way to accomplish what I'm looking for? Thanks in advance!